# Could anyone please show me the concept of the phrase?

Tags: meaning

> Fazio (1972) has suggested that the latter are largely a result of
>   **“vicarious learning family dependency”** rather than of traumatic conditioning; most of his subjects lacked any real contact with the
>   feared insects.

Would you please show me how to rephrase the bold part in another way, but with the ver words?

Extracted from [Insects in Psychiatry](http://www.insects.org/ced2/insects_psych.html).

Comment: -1 because the sentence contains "the latter". You should really quote the preceding sentence(s) too, so we know what "latter" refers to.

Comment: The phrase "vicarious learning family dependency" is awkward to the point of being ungrammatical, and would probably benefit from some hyphens (vicarious-learning family-dependency); but have you looked up the word "vicarious" in a dictionary?

Comment: Finally, the text explains itself. The sentence you quoted offers a periphrasis for "vicarious" and in the passage below this sentence, there are  examples clarifying what the author means by "family dependency".

Comment: It means "*The patient learned to be afraid of insects from her parents or other family members, rather than through direct, traumatic interactions with insects*". And it is horrible, horrible English. I can only hope that "*family dependency*" or "*vicarious learning*" or both are fixed phrases or well-known jargon in psychiatric circles. I can't imagine the blog's author expected a layman to derive what that meant from the simple composition of those four words.

Comment: _with the ver words_... what do you mean by _ver_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the sentence you quoted without any trouble (but I recommend that you give a url in future here): http://www.insects.org/ced2/insects_psych.html

In a case like this, you should always look up the original author's work.  Here, since you don't understand Weinstein, and he's quoting Fazio, you should look up the Fazio article.

Here's the Fazio abstract: http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/abn/80/2/183/

It says, "Ss' interview data support vicarious learning family-dependency interpretations rather than traumatic conditioning interpretations of the etiology of phobias."  The hyphen definitely helps, don't you think?

If it's still not clear to you, then your next step would be to look at Fazio's whole article.

By the way, Weinstein's prose has a lot of problems.  Please don't feel discouraged if you have trouble understanding him.

Edit:

Sorry, I just saw your link.  Sorry I missed it earlier!

Another edit:

I just noticed your question about family dependency.  I was able to download the pdf through a university library.  Here's a paragraph from the Fazio article:
"It appeared from the interviewing data that vicarious learning situations (Bandura, 1969, p. 167) might play a significant role in the etiology of common phobias. That is, a family member (typically the mother) dramatically expresses some unpleasant concern over insects and this concern is imitated by the child. "Eager to please" and/or dependent children with "overprotective" parents (Andrews, 1966) would seem to be more likely to acquire the phobic attitude or reaction. Persistent and successful escape/avoidance responding (Solomon & Wynn, 1954), perhaps initially elicited by a teasing brother, might account for the strengthening and "spreading" of the fear. In this regard, considerate relatives and friends coming to the patient's rescue probably do more to maintain or enhance than to remove the phobic reaction (Andrews, 1966; Costello, 1970).

Understanding and treatment of phobias has come a long way since the early 70's.  Take a look at Exposure and Response Prevention and the International OCD foundation.

Comment: First off all thank you so much all for taking the time. However, would anyone please show me the following in a more readily aspect? family-dependency